# Any differences between these 2 ways of asynchronously loading images?

Tags: javascript, html

Given this HTML (the data URI is just an empty image):

`<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
 data-src="/path/to/img.jpg" width="100" height="100">`

What are the performance implications of these approaches? If they're *mostly the same*, should I go with option A and avoid declaring a function within a loop?

#### Option A:

```
document.onload = function() {
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]');

    for (let i = 0, length = images.length; i < length; i++) {
        images[i].src = images[i].getAttribute('data-src');

        // And optionally
        images[i].removeAttribute('data-src');
    }
};
```

#### Option B:

```
document.onload = function() {
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]');

    for (let i = 0, length = images.length; i < length; i++) {
        let downloadingImage = new Image();

        downloadingImage.onload = function() {
            images[i].src = this.src;   
        };

        downloadingImage.src = images[i].getAttribute('data-src');

        // And optionally
        images[i].removeAttribute('data-src');
    }
};
```

Comment: Ideally... don't do any of this at all.  Let the browser deal with it.  With what you have, you're forcing the browser to buffer your fake images, convert the base64 to binary, load them, draw them, just to turn around and get nuked by some script almost immediately.  Browsers are also configured individually.  Some people may not want your images.  Others may have their own tweaks.  Unless you have a very specialized reason for doing what you're doing... don't.

Comment: I do have a good reason: removing render-blocking elements from the page in order to speed load times. That's why the images are downloaded only when the DOM is ready. It's a very common practice when you try to optimize the critical rendering path. I'm just trying to figure out differences between these 2 options. Also, the image is the smallest transparent thing possible without making an HTTP request, so I don't see how that's hard for a browser to deal with.

Comment: I guess the best way to know is to run some benchmarks. Try both and check which one is faster. I'd go for Option A but who knows.

Comment: @johnRivs You realize your images aren't going to block rendering, right?  And, that the browser can download them while rendering the page, right?  If you actually cared about people with slower connections, you wouldn't do what you're doing.  I'm well aware that it's common practice, and also well aware of how bad of an idea it almost always is.  Instead of letting the browser do a lot of things at once, you're chunking it out effectively slowing your page performance, especially for those with slower connections who need the optimization more than others.

Comment: @Bras isn't there value in deferring the download of images that are below the fold? That way the browser is free to download other important resources sooner and then download the images that the user can't see on initial render. How exactly is it slower? It's only changing the order.

Comment: @Brad I tested deferring vs. not deferring to see if the results align with my expectations. I'm using browser.png and 2 more images that can be seen in the following screenshots. Not deferring: the images prevent the browser from dealing with the 2 most important scripts sooner (vendor.common.js and app.js) http://i.imgur.com/JUh2WFg.png 2) Deferring: the opposite http://i.imgur.com/tcly6pZ.png 3) Deferring above-the-fold images: what I said in my previous comment http://i.imgur.com/U9MymM8.png

Comment: @johnRivs I'd have to see your page and scripts to see what's going on, but image download doesn't prevent your script for loading.  You probably have some handler for the page being loaded rather than DOM ready.  Trust me, this is the most optimized part of your browser... they got it right for almost all cases.  There's no reason to do what you're doing.